# How check in junit method was invoked from super class or from descendant class in java?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, methods, junit

Code:

```
 ClassBase {
    protected method1() {

     protected methodA (par1, par2){

     ... } }

  };
 ClassA  extends ClassBase {
   @Override
     protected methodA (par1, par2){
       .....
       };   
  };
```

After:

```
ClassA testClass=new ClassA();
 testClass.methodA();
```

Is it possible to test (may be junit) that when running method methodA, if methodA from descendant classA was invoked ? 
Thanks.

Comment: from what I recall, this is a case of hiding inherited methods (MethodA from ClassBase, in this case). If you want to call methodA from ClassBase, you can do something like: ClassA obj; obj.super().methodA;. Otherwise, the ClassA method will be called.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything to test. If you have a ClassA object (you can easily test this) and you call methodA on it, you could be sure that the overriding method from ClassA is called. That is a guaranty of the Java language. It's even guarantied if you cast a ClassA object to its super class.

You can use the override annotation to make sure that you really override a method in ClassA, if you want to test this. Or you can test on the specific result. Your overriding method is probably doing something different than your overwritten method (if both methods to the same thing, it makes no sense to overwrite it). Test on that difference.

Comment: And if seeing is believing, you can use some printouts once to convince you of this, but like @Thomas Uhrig says, this is what happens